# Batch Script - create an .XML file - name based on every .PNG file in folder

Tags: xml, batch-file

I'm new at programming + using MIT version of Torque 2D game engine. 
For some reason the engine requires that images have an XML (.TAML) file 
associated to it. This file should be named based on the image file name.

I have a have hundred's of .png files that need an XML file added. I thought that writing a script would be the best approach to solving this problem. I need some help/guidance as to how to go about writing a batch script that would help me accomplish this task.

Here is an example of the logic for the script:

1.The main folder is the "assets" folder.
The batch file would run and first check the "assets" for images.

a) If it found no images it would check all subfolders.

b) If it found a file it would create a text file using the png file name

c) it would fill in the text file header and fill AssetName= & ImageName= fields with the png file name.

d) it would append the .asset.taml extension save and close and continue the loop.

e) when done print success message and exit. (if I want to get fancy I can keep track of how many files were added.)

Simulation:
run program in the assets folder.

assets/images/check.png

the batch file would create an xml text file named:

check.asset.taml  (the .taml is the XML file)

The XML file's content would look something like this:

```
<ImageAsset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../Torque2D.xsd"
            AssetName="check"
            ImageFile="check.png"/>
```

the batch script would continue and find the next file: (notice it found a new sub directory)
assets/images/backgrounds/background.png

and output a new xml in the proper directory

background.asset.taml

```
The XML file Content: 
<ImageAsset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../Torque2D.xsd"
            AssetName="background"
            ImageFile="background.png"/>
```

I would appreciate any help and direction on how to go about writing this script.
not sure if "C", "C++", Python, other language would be best to write it in?

Thanks,

-Joe

Comment: should `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` change its location if the file is found deeper in sub directories?

Comment: Hello npocmaka, The schema would be in its own directory out side of the assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=U:\destdir"
SET /a filecount=0
SET "and_subdirs="
:again
PUSHD "%targetdir%"
FOR %and_subdirs% %%a IN (
  "*.png"
 ) DO (
  SET /a filecount+=1
  >"%%~dpna.taml" (
   ECHO(^<ImageAsset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../Torque2D.xsd"
   ECHO(         AssetName="%%~na"
   ECHO(         ImageFile="%%~nxa"/^>
  )
)
popd
IF NOT DEFINED and_subdirs IF %filecount%==0 SET "and_subdirs=/r"& GOTO again
ECHO(%filecount% files found
IF DEFINED and_subdirs ECHO(Subdirectories were scanned

GOTO :EOF
```

This should fix your problem. You would need to change the setting of `targetdir` to suit your circumstances.

Comment: The schema file will be contained in the same location for all images.Ill give her a shot and see if i run into any issues. Thank you for your answer.